# pyCurl and BytesIO for scraping a website

Tags: python, pycurl, bytesio

I would have a need for scraping. Specifically, I use Pycurl and BytesIO.

The following code:

```
c = pycurl.Curl()
page = BytesIO()
c.setopt(c.INTERFACE, "tun0")
c.setopt(c.USERAGENT, userAgent)
c.setopt(pycurl.CAINFO, certifi.where())
c.setopt(c.URL, URL)
c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, page)
c.perform()
```

Until yesterday, `page.getvalue()` would return the html of the page which I would then pass to bs4. Today, however, I notice that it returns a string in bytes that I can't even decode into utf-8 because it returns an error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

How can I get in the string type the content of the url, in order to pass it to bs4 and scrape?

Comment: Post the first 200 or so bytes and perhaps we can guess at the correct encoding. does pycurl expose the response headers in any way? Perhaps there's a "Content-Encoding" included in the response.

Comment: display it without decoding - see what you get in this string. Maybe it uses different encoding then `utf-8`. Or maybe it send byte file instead of text/HTML file.

Comment: BTW: `bs4` can get bytes - you don't have to decode it.

Answer (score 0):

The data you retrieved is not valid UTF-8, therefore it cannot be decoded automatically.

- Use the headers returned with the response to identify what encoding the body is supposed to be in. If the encoding is not UTF-8, decode using the correct decoding.
- If the body is claimed to be in UTF-8 but contains invalid data, use the second argument to [bytes.decode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) to specify what to do about the invalid data.